# Read from remote host github.com: The connection was aborted

Tags: git, push

I'm using git to manage my project via gitBash.

Firstly, I've created a respository named anDemo then I've cloned it locally. For testing, I created two files: a.txt and b.txt.

I can push all of them successfully. Next,I want move my project folder(size:32MB) to my local respository so I could push it to github. However,I failed when I push the project folder.
It remind me connection absorbed.
The error:

```
Administrator@MS-20160922OGNK /e/gitResp2 (master)
$ git push origin master
  Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/Administrator/.ssh/id_rsa':
  Counting objects: 1073, done.
  Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
  Compressing objects: 100% (929/929), done.
  Read from remote host github.com: The connection was aborted
  fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Invalid argument
  fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
  error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:anyongjian/test.git'
```

[connection absorbed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiQim.png)

You can see,although I pulled before push and it failed as before.
And when I try again,I captured the message like this:

```
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/Administrator/.ssh/id_rsa
Counting objects: 1073, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (929/929), done.
Writing objects:  57% (612/1072), 6.95 MiB | 2.00 KiB/s   s
```

As you can see,the upload speed is 2.00Kib/s,I guess is speed low to 0 Kib/s，so it absorbed,is it? 
I am very glad to hear any advices.

Thank in advance.

Comment: did you commit any change before pushing again ?

Comment: Is this failure reproducible, meaning, does it keep happening?  I don't see errors like this too often, but when I do, I close the bash, reopen it, and try again later.

Comment: yes,I have already commited changes.@chenchuk

Comment: error keep happening.I restart gitBash ,and try again and failed again.@TimBiegeleisen